# Unique vectors that can result from bootstrapping

Tags: r, combinatorics

My question concerns the unique number of vectors that can result from bootstrapping. Ie I have a vector of length 12 with the following elements : 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 and I would like to know if an efficient algorithm exists for generating the total number of bootstrapped vectors that can result from this input vector.

It would be nice to have a solution in R, but a formula will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Each element can either be a $1$ or a $2$ and we are sampling with replacement so there are $2^{12} = 4096$ possible samples.  The probability of any given bootstrap sample can also be calculated in a straightforward way using the composition of the original sample.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works for permutations of the vector, but I was hoping for the combinations (or ideally, unique summations) that can result from the input. Sorry my question was not more explicit

Comment: $\{12, 13, \ldots, 24 \}$ is the set of all possible sums.